# Setting slf4j properties

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

I'm trying to see if there's a way to set the **slf4j.detectLoggerNameMismatch** logger property in Spring Boot via the application.yml file.

Extensive google searches have found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need config this property in the system properties.

This property is loaded by `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`

Comment: You mean using -D?  I was trying to keep config off the command line: are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a @Bean that looks at the property value from your .yml and then calls System.setProperty(...). Though I'm not sure if SLF4J is already initialized by that point; it might be to late.

Comment: I think it might be too late...  I currently have   System.setProperty("slf4j.detectLoggerNameMismatch", "true") at the very top of my main() and it has no effect.